# why combobox SelectedValued Throw exception when there is nothing Seleceted

Tags: c#

I am working on Windows Form Application .. In which there are many Text boxes as well as Combo Box this is my data entry form ...
when i inserting data into database i got following Exception....

```
   string NickName = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();//object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Nick Name is optional Field in my case...
My Question is why combobox SelectedValued Throw exception when there is nothing Seleceted? How to overcome this?..
Any help would be appreciated .thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to convert  a `null`  object

```
 string NickName = comboBox1.SelectedValue == null? "":comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

> My Question is why combobox SelectedValued Throw exception when there is nothing Seleceted?

when nothig is selected `comboBox1.SelectedValue` returns `null` and if you call any member on `null` it will throw `NullReferenceException`.

> How to overcome this?

You can check for `null` before trying to access its value.
or
You can check for its `SelectedIndex` value.

**Solutions:** You can use any one the following methods to solve the issue.

**Method 1:** using `if-condition`

```
string NickName = string.Empty; 
if(comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
   NickName = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

**Method 2:** using `conditional(ternary ?:) operator`

```
string NickName = (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null) ? 
     comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

**Method 3 :** using `null-coalescing ??` operator

```
string NickName =(string) comboBox1.SelectedValue ?? string.Empty;
```

**Method 4 :** by checking the `SelectedIndex`

```
string NickName = (comboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0) ? 
     comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() : string.Empty;
```